# handle and bind json request in symfony2

Tags: javascript, json, rest, symfony

I send PUT json request but cant bind my javascript's model to entity via form, how to do it:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $fb = $this->get('fire_php');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $progress = $em->getRepository('CodeCatsPanelBundle:Progress')->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProgressType(), $progress);

    $fb->log($request->getContent());
    //from firebug:
    //PUT http://pc.t/app_dev.php/panel/progress/5?_dc=1397662229471
    //{"id":5,"title":"aaa","description":"lllll","started":"2014-03-18"}
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $fb->log($form->isValid());
    //false :(
    return new JsonResponse(array('success' => true));
    }
}
```

in progress type:

```
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('started', 'date', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        ));
```

Comment: In the method setDefaultOptions of ProgressType add 'csrf_protection' => true for disable csrf protection and try again

Answer (score 0):

You should deserialize your JSON data into an array, and feed that array to the form.

Comment: what method you prefer to feed that array? I use submit now